# Find processes listening on the wildcard address in `lsof`

Tags: tcp, lsof

Using `lsof`, I can find all of the processes with a TCP socket listening for connections:

`lsof -Pni -sTCP:LISTEN`

e.g.:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER  FD  TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
cupsd     662   root  7u  IPv6   11108      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     662   root  8u  IPv4   11109      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
rsyncd    905   root  4u  IPv4   13379      0t0  TCP *:873 (LISTEN)
...
```

Is there any way (without piping the output to another program, like `grep`, `awk`, or `sed`) to limit this to TCP sockets listening on the wildcard address?  Tried:

```
$ lsof -Pni @0.0.0.0 -sTCP:LISTEN
lsof: incomplete Internet address specification: -i @0.0.0.0
```

and

```
$ lsof -Pni @\* -sTCP:LISTEN
lsof: unknown host name (*) in: -i @*
```

Alternatively, is there any way to generically negate the conditions passed to `lsof`?

Comment: Looks like a bug in lsof to me!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `lsof`?

`netstat -tulpn` will show the processes that are listening on any given port. Processes listening on all IPs will show as 0.0.0.0:

Comment: But this command shows also processes which listen on a specific IP, like `lsof -Pni -sTCP:LISTEN`?!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with `lsof`. There's no way to specify the wildcard address without matching **just** the wildcard:

```
lsof -nP -sTCP:LISTEN -i@0.0.0.0:1-65535
```

would seem to do it but it captures both the actual wildcard address (INADDR_ANY) as well as the semantic "wildcard", ie any address at all. Interestingly, `[::]` is not acceptable for a v6 wildcard selection. `lsof` does support negations but not for addresses, so eg you cannot do something to filter out localhost.

It can be done with `ss(8)` but the process name is difficult to parse.

```
# ss -nlt src 0.0.0.0
State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("sshd",pid=939,fd=3))
```

The part in `""` (`sshd` above) is the process name, not the username as confusingly implied by the label.

IMO it would generally be easier to filter the `lsof` output than to parse  the `ss` output. Or to process the output of `/proc/net/tcp` directly.